# How To Embed a HTML Source Inside Another?

Tags: html, embed

I have two HTML source files. One called `index.html` and the other `embed.html`, but I want to embed the second file inside the index one, using HTML this is possible? If not, maybe using JavaScript or VBScript?

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming - the tag wiki explicitly says that the embedded tag does NOT apply to components embedded on a web page, see stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, I would use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

In general, if both documents are valid documents, you cannot simply drop the content of one into another and expect the result to be valid HTML (for example, you will end up with two `<body>` tags (either nested or not), which is not valid HTML.

This is why frames exist, though they are not very user friendly.

Comment: Thanks very much! Also, they are nice because it is compatible with mobile browsers

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this won't work for any inline javascript contained in the document loaded into the IFRAME... it won't have access to the parent page's DOM?

Comment: @Michael - True for inline JS. However, the OP was only concerned with HTML.